# Junit xml report don't report each test case when 'Karate' parallel runner is used

Tags: junit4, karate

I am running 5 API test scenarios using karate. When I run the test in non-parallel mode using @RunWith(Karate.class) then in xml generated by surefire-reports, all scenarios are reported individually as .

```
<testcase classname="[healthCheck]" name="[1:3] Check health check API returns status code 200" time="2.846"/>
  <testcase classname="[healthCheckHeader]" name="[1:6] Check health check API returns status code 200" time="0.285"/>
  <testcase classname="[userLogin]" name="[1:3] Check User Login API returns status code 200" time="0.108"/>
  <testcase classname="[requestChaining]" name="[1:7] chain request demo" time="0.521"/>
  <testcase classname="[viewRequests]" name="[1:10] Check View Requests API returns status code 200" time="0.278"/>
```

However, when I use karate parallel runner, then each scenario is not reported individually.

```
<testcase classname="demoTest.AutomationSuiteParallelCucRunner" name="testParallel" time="10.917"/>
```

I want to have similar report for parallel runner as generated when tests executed in non-parallel mode.

Here is the code for running tests in non-parallel mode:

```
@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class AutomationSuiteTest {
}
```

Here is the code for running tests in parallel mode:

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})

public class AutomationSuiteParallelCucRunner {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
        KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 3, karateOutputPath);
        assertTrue("SCENARIO FAILURES!!", stats.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: The JUnit XML you are looking at is the wrong one, please read the docs carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports Look inside `target/surefire-reports`. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57379073/143475 If you still have a problem, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi Peter,
Thanks for your reply.


I am looking inside target/surefire-reports and there is xml report for my each scenario like demoTest.userLogin.xml' and there is one xml TEST-demoTest.AutomationSuiteParallelCucRunner.xml'.


This file 'AutomationSuiteParallelCucRunner' has different content when I run a test in parallel mode and non-parallel mode.

Comment: I have nothing more to add to what I already posted

Answer (score 1):

Having struggled with this myself, the solution was surprisingly simple, though not really covered in the karate docs (as of this time).

The point is: when using the parallel runner in this manner, there is from JUnit's perspective just *one* unit test - the single method annotated with `@Test`. So this single test is all that's listed in `target/surefire-reports`. Karate doesn't seem to hook into the JUnit execution or so, so that's it.

But - and that was the missing piece for me - the karate runner itself can generate JUnit XML files. You just have to call `.outputJunitXml(true)` when creating it. This causes it to generate JUnit XML files in the karate report dir along with the HTML report and (optionally) cucumber JSON files:

```java
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;

public class KarateTestRunner {
  @Test
  public void runParallel() {
    final Results results = Runner.path("classpath:api/karate")
        .outputCucumberJson(true)
        .outputJunitXml(true)     # <----
        .parallel(8);

    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount());
  }
}
```