# How to add an option to Cucumber report to remove scenarios that have a certain tag

Tags: cucumber, karate

I want to have an option on the cucumber report to mute/hide scenarios with a given tag from the results and numbers.

We have a bamboo build that runs our karate repository of features and scenarios.  At the end it produces nice cucumber html reports.  On the "overview-features.html" I would like to have an option added to the top right, which includes "Features", "Tags", "Steps" and "Failures", that says "Excluded Fails" or something like that.  That when clicked provides the same exact information that the overview-features.html does, except that any scenario that's tagged with a special tag, for example @bug=abc-12345, is removed from the report and excluded from the numbers.

Why I need this.  We have some existing scenarios that fail.  They fail due to defects in our own software, that might not get fixed for 6 months to a year.  We've tagged them with a specified tag, "@bug=abc-12345".  I want them muted/excluded from the cucumber report that's produced at the end of the bamboo build for karate so I can quickly look at the number of passed features/scenarios and see if it's 100% or not.  If it is, great that build is good.  If not, I need to look into it further as we appear to have some regression.  Without these scenarios that are expected to fail, and continue to fail until they're resolved, it is very tedious and time consuming to go through all the individual feature file reports and look at the failing scenarios and then look into why. I don't want them removed completely as when they start to pass I need to know so I can go back and remove the tag from the scenario.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karate 1.0 has overhauled the reporting system with the following key changes.

- after the `Runner` completes you can massage the results and even re-try some tests
- you can inject a custom HTML report renderer

This will require you to get into the details (some of this is not documented yet) and write some Java code. If that is not an option, you have to consider that what you are asking for is not supported by Karate.

If you are willing to go down that path, here are the links you need to get started.

a) Example of how to "post process" result-data before rendering a report: [`RetryTest.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/retry/RetryTest.java) and also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971681/143475

b) The code responsible for "pluggable" reports, where you can implement a new [`SuiteReports`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/report/SuiteReports.java) in theory. And in the `Runner`, there is a `suiteReports()` method you can call to provide your implementation.

Also note that there is an experimental "doc" keyword, by which you can inject custom HTML into a test-report: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1338892932691070976

Also see: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1427638609578967047