# Karate: Comments in Scenario Outline do not show in HTML reports

Tags: karate

I have noticed that commented lines in Scenario Outline do not appear in the HTML report steps even though this is not the case for regular Scenarios.

By any chance, is this intended or is it an overlooked bug?

I am aware that this issue is very minor and low in priority but it is helpful for cases like mine, whose lines of code can get a bit long. In-line comments help in documenting and separating blocks of code in my test scenarios.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be overlooked. This is certainly not a priority for the project developers, you are welcome to contribute code.

Custom reports can be easy if you know Java, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475

EDIT - at the very least, please submit a simple sample so that the problem is clear, following the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue