# Need to send test results in email body but emailable-report.html is not getting created in Target folder

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, karate

I am trying to send test results in email body through Jenkins. I have done my API automation in Karate and Cucumber Framework. I am able to attach overview.html report on mail but unable to send test results in email body. How are I do that? These are the folders which are getting created on my jenkins workspace.

No emailable-report.html or index.html is getting created in target folder.

I need to send test results in email Body not as attachment.

Comment: see this answer also, and if that doesn't help - assume there is no direct solution and you have to contribute code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475