# Is there a way to see the non-truncated version of tags of the format @env=a or @service=b in karate-tags.html?

Tags: karate

The karate-tags.html table is a great way to see the tags used in each Feature in one location, but tags of the format `@a=b` (i.e., `@env=a`, `@service=b` or `@parallel=false`) get truncated to everything before the `=`. In other words, if you ran a Feature with the aforementioned tags, karate-tags.html would show `env`, `service` and `parallel` for that Feature. Is this expected/intended behavior so a user can (for example) see everywhere the `env` tag is used, regardless of what environment value is provided?

If so, is there a way to see the full tag names for all Features in one location? The goal would be to find a way to see all tags that are used when a collection of Features is called.

Comment: Please contribute code :) Else, please consider writing your own report: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475