# Print logs only when the tests failed in karate

Tags: karate

With Karate API tests, I would like to print the request and reponse only when the test fails.
How can I achieve that in karate.

Consider the below scenarios

```
Feature: Validate Addition.
  Background:
  Scenario Outline: Verify Addition
    * def sum = <num1> + <num2>
    And match sum == 10
    * print "number1:" + num1 + " number2:" + num2
    Examples:
      | num1 | num2 |
      | 5    | 5    |
      | 7    | 3    |
      | 3    | 8    |
      | 1    | 5    |
      | 1    | 9    |
```

In the above scenario I get the print for every iteration. Is it possible to print the numbers only when the match fails.

I think it would be more efficient if we can have such option.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that it is not possible. You can try contributing code to make this happen. Or maybe you should use REST-assured or Selenium - those sound more like a good fit for you, based on all your questions.

One thought is that you can switch off all logging by making the levels `ERROR` etc. and then write some custom hook. Refer to hooks here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944060/143475

Also refer to how to create custom reports here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475