# Integrating Karate with Serenity BDD to generate serenity reports

Tags: karate, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Trying to find if Karate can be integrated with Serenity BDD framework so we can generate Serenity reports from Karate test runs.
Karate does emit cucumber json but can serenity just act as report generator?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Karate is open-source so you can try contributing.

You can also consider writing your own report: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475

Comment: In serenity manual and automation test cases can be kept together and the final results can be updated to reflect overall status , is that possible in karate as well or its true to the definetion of executable specification?

Comment: @Rohitdev the answer is no. I think you have some unrealistic expectations of BDD, so please read this (and pass this on to your teams or leaders if needed): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475 - there is also a "dry run" concept that you can use to manage un-automated scenarios: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1427638609578967047

Comment: The reason we want to do this some of the use cases are expensive to automate as well as the way infrastructure security is setup and are flaky so would be manually executed but either ways they are user facing acceptance tests. The idea here is to have a single report spitted out which can be manually updated , something like this https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/manual-tests.html

Comment: @Rohitdev take some time to read and fully absorb the links I posted above, I have nothing else to add to my comments

Comment: Sure Peter, Thanks! will got through the readup you shared.