# Can i add an extra column in table present in cucumber html reports for karate?

Tags: cucumber, karate, junit5, cucumber-junit

[image: sample karate cucumber report]

Like if i have to add in "Features" section an extra column to represent the "size" of feature.
So what steps should i follow in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is the third party report.

If you want to write custom reports in Karate that **may** be possible, but for now, please assume that it is not (directly) supported: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475

Comment: Thanks peter for the quick response..but i need more clarity regarding the SuiteReports.java file where after calling the summaryReports method the template is not getting generated in the given file path.

Comment: @IbadurRehman sorry I can't help more than this

Comment: Edit: Thanks peter for the quick response..but i need more clarity regarding the SuiteReports.java file that can we edit those karate generated summary report through SuiteReports.java on the basis of which cucumber reports are generated.

Comment: @IbadurRehman sorry I can't help more than this