# Is there a way to see all the Scenario names and the Scenario teststeps in the karate report when parent feature file is calling other feature files?

Tags: karate

I have a parent feature file that calls other feature files. In the html report, i can see only the scenarios of my parent feature file. The scenarios of the feature files called by the parent is not coming in the report. If we expand the highlighted parts in the report then only we are able to see the called scenarios. In the xml or json report also we are seeing the same. Is there a way we can view the called scenarios data also in the xml or json report?[image: html]
[image: xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and this is not a priority for Karate. The recommendation is that you focus your primary flow in the main feature and call other features only for setup and utilities.

That said, Karate is open-source and anyone is welcome to contribute and make the reports better. Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what specifically you're looking for, but if you click the hyper link on the lines with ">>" it will display all the information for the given feature file being called.
[image]