# Generate user defined Summary Report in karate

Tags: karate

for my Inhouse CI tool, I need to provide output of the karate Execution as a json file in the project folder, with below keys.

{passed:15, failed 8}

this should be a consolidated values of the executed feature/s.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this yourself by using the output of the `Results` object in Java. Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475