An option in Karate to display Warning messages in Yellow Color
I am using
a. Karate version: 1.2.0
b. HTML report: (paste into browser to view)
My query as below,
I would like to know if there is some command to display some message using * print or * karate.log() which emits messages in logs if Yellow or Orange color. so that the message can be inferred as warning message. Ideal for situation like scenario had to be aborted due to some conditional logic where we just report a warning message to be displayed in yellow/orange.
currently karate.abort() though aborts execution shows green, karate.fail() as usual in red color inside the logs. please make available an option to show warning messages in yellow either in existing commands or introduce new command. requesting inputs thanks.

karate.abort() - expected aborted step to show in yellow but showed in green color in logs
karate.fail() - shows in red color inside logs.
bing copilot suggested options to include orange color tags and changes to karate.config - It did not work.


https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/abort/abort.feature , this example serves the purpose. thanks

Since no other team has requested this, your best option is to write your own report (refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475) or consider contributing code to Karate.
Also check whether this setting has any effect:
* configure abortedStepsShouldPass = false

Please note that enhancements to old versions are not supported.
