Why is Karate scenario and scenario outline generating parantheses before the name?
Am using a simple Karate runner to run my features. But the karate html output is generating my scenario thus. Its adding the [1:1:22] as prefix to the Card is not used scenario name. How can i remove the parantheses being added to the Scenario name?

Scenario: [1.1:22] Card is not used

These are my depedencies and my Karate Test Runner
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>${karate.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;

public class MyTestRunner {
   @DisplayName("My Card Feature")
   @Karate.Test
   Karate runCardTestFeature() {
      return Karate.run("classpath:features/card-test-feature.feature")
                   .outputHtmlReport(true)
                   .outputJunitXml(true)
                   .backupReportDir(false);
   }
}


This system has been used for a long time and indicates the scenario index, example-row if applicable and the line-number.
If you need full control over the report, you should consider writing your own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475
